# Android AlphaAnimation causes black box

Tags: android, animation

I'm applying an AlphaAnimation to a Button.  The animation is extremely simple.

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="500"/>
```

On the emulator, the button fades out nicely with no discernable artifacts.  On actual devices (Nexus One & Motorola Droid), there is a noticeable black artifact from the actual frame of the button.

Is there any way to avoid this?  It looks like crap.

Emulator:

[Emulator http://img.skitch.com/20100716-e66fgyg4pdyium15cu4e4ijr9c.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100716-e66fgyg4pdyium15cu4e4ijr9c.jpg)

Device:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100716-fhs149r5ftkm3pte1sajkfnabh.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100716-fhs149r5ftkm3pte1sajkfnabh.jpg)

(Images have been doctored because it's hard to capture the same fade state during an animation, but that's exactly what it looks like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the answer is that Android does a crap job of cross-fading.  Marking this as the answer for lack of a better explanation.